# Hystrix dependent commands failure suggestion

Tags: hystrix

I have 2 commands
1) DebitCommand (Debit Credit card)

2) CreditCommand (Credit to Account)

From our use case perspective Debit and Credit combination is one atomic operation which are connected to 2 different systems (Rest call).

When CreditCommand circuit breaker is short circuited it doesn't make sense to debit or else we need to refund the money back. which actually increases an unnecessary call. Is there any way which hystrix solves this.

My thoughts:

Approach 1: Merge DebitCommand and CreditCommand into a single credit command
Approach 2: In DebitCommand execute call some how get the status of the circuit of CreditCommand and allow only when Circuit Breaker is opened or Half Opened or revert back.

If any one who has experienced with this use case, could you please help how you have solved this use case

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 2** Querying circuit state as a basis for whether to place a call, ( in pseudo-code: `if (circuit is healthy) { Place call through circuit }` ) is not a sensible way to proceed, even if available.  In a highly-concurrent/multi-threaded environment, the circuit state could change between evaluating the if condition and placing the inner call.  So this approach offers no guarantee that the second call will succeed.